# Regex on memcached key?

Tags: memcached

Is it possible to grab a list of memcached key based on some regex? I understand that one solution is to store the key in the database and grab the list when I need to delete those keys. This means that, it is going to incur additional cost to the db.

I was wondering if there is another way to do it without DB overhead.

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that. The documentation suggests [a way to simulate a namespace](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Simulating_Namespaces_with_key_prefixes), but that's it.

Comment: Thanks :) I found this: http://code.google.com/p/memcached-tag/
I wonder we can add_tag gradually... Any idea?

Comment: Documentation url has changed: now http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingTricks

Comment: Comments with broken links are not useful!

Answer (score 0):

memcached is fast because it doesn't do this sort of thing.

If it did all the stuff your database could do, it'd be as fast as your database and someone would need to come along and build something with more constrained semantics that optimized for speed over functionality.

Answer (score -1):

```
    private static string CleanKey(string key)
    {
        var regex = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]");
        var clean = regex.Replace(key, string.Empty);
        return clean.Length > 250 ? clean.Substring(0, 250) : clean;
    }
```