# How to remove/flush specific keyset's from MemCache server?

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, memcached, spymemcached

I have few key's stored in the MemCached server. Like...

```
KEY-2312sdasd78
KEY-5lk65klk343
KEY-klk34k3lkl3
TEST-34k3l4k3l4
TEST-kl3k2lk3l2
```

Now, I want to remove the key's from MemCached server which are start with "KEY".

I have tried to find google but there is no RegEX based support in MemCached.

Does anybody faced this kind of issues, and what is the optimum work around for this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate: [Regex on memcached key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497159/regex-on-memcached-key)

Also See http://code.google.com/p/memcached-tag/

I think something like this is much easier with something like Redis because it:

- [Supports Transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions)
- Supports atomic data structures like Lists

So in Redis when you add a key,value you will add the key to some giant global list in the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this without knowing that the keys are.

The only way that you could do something like this is by prefixing each set of keys with something common, e.g. `KEY-KEYSET1-`.  You could then invalidate them all by internally bumping `1` to `2` in your code, which means that the existing values will not be accessed and eventually expire.

Comment: I know, that is why i am asking for help to remove key's which start with "KEY".

Comment: And as per the first sentence, you can't do it unless you know exactly what they are.

Comment: key-by-key way, that i know. I want to do it in one shot. Assume there is 1 Lac Key. Think iteration of those key and invalidate one-by-one.

Comment: There's no `deleteBulk()` method in spymemcached, if that's what you are looking for.